# My question is about intents in android studio. How can i send data between activities through intents

Tags: android

Is it possible to send data of multiple Edit texts to 2nd activity and show that data on single Text View? If possible than how?

Comment: yes this is possible, you can use intent.putextra() for pass edit text value and second activity you will get this valu and send it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: get and merge edit text data then send it to second activity through intent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to write this code where you call new activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("textOfEditText1",editText1.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("textOfEditText2",editText2.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

And This code in your second activity's onCreate() method

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s= b.get("textOfEditText1");
    String s2=b.get("textOfEditText2");
    textView.setText(s+s2);
```

Comment: I assume you need text of different EditTexts separately

Comment: i am doing in same way but it shows null value of first string but shows the correct value of second string

Comment: Copy paste the code you have written and also the error log